# Enzyme check if component mounted without errors on prop types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I am creating integration test for a components to test its interface and I am mounting it like so

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component boolVal={()=>{}} />
```

In the `Component` I have marked `boolVal` prop as boolean value and when mounting I am getting an expected warning:

```
`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `boolVal` of type `function` supplied to `Component`, expected `boolean`.`
```

This is correct, but I'd like the test to fail.

How can I archive this please?

Comment: You can check how React itself [tests](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8ba820a699ed337cf4f42a5743313cb925b6f97b/src/isomorphic/classic/types/__tests__/ReactPropTypes-test.js#L28) this functionality. Put a spy on `console.error()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dmitri's answer, here is a test that spies on `console.error`. Test fails when the props fail validation:

```
describe.only('Test Component', () => {

    const sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();

    beforeEach(function() {
        sandbox.spy(console, 'error');
    });

    it('mounts', function () {
        shallow(
            <Component boolVal={()=>{}} />
        );
        assert.isFalse(console.error.called);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        sandbox.restore();
    });
});
```